Using Bogus's Faker<T>, how do you pass a param down to contained members?
I have, essentially, a class that is stored in two different places:
// In Sql
public class Crud{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public CrudDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

// In Blobs
public class CrudDetail{
  public int Id { get; set; } // To match parent's Id
  public string Content { get; set; }
}

How do I create a Faker generator to assign the parent's Id to the Detail's id?
      return new Faker<Crud>()
        .RuleFor(c => c.Id, f => f.Random.Int())
        .RuleFor(c => c.Title, f => f.Commerce.ProductName())

        // .RuleFor((d, c) => d.Id, d => c.Id) // Error: The name 'c' does not exist in the current context.

        .RuleFor(c => c.Detail, f => new Faker<CrudDetail>()
          .RuleFor(d => d.Id, c => c.Id) // Error: 'Faker' does not contain a definition for 'Id'...

        .RuleFor((d, c) => d.Id, d => c.Id)
          .RuleFor(d => d.Content, f => f.Lorem.Lines(_rando.Next(3, 15)))
        );

Thanks for any advice!
